# iOS UIScrollView add elements programmatically from bottom to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, chat

I'm trying to create a chat view where the messages get added from the bottom to the top (like facebook).

The view has 2 states, the first state is without scrolling enabled (the messages are added from the bottom to the top but they disappear when they get out of the viewport)

The second state let the user scroll to the top to see the previous messages.

I don't know if I'm clear, here's some screenshots :

[Chat message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxyxt.png)
[Chat message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZjA0.png)

Can you explain how to do this programmatically ? Actually, it's working WITHOUT the UIScrollView, but when I try to make it work inside of it, it's a mess.

I tried so many different ways, and none are working properly...

I don't understand why ScrollView is so hard to work with, I never saw a native component in any language who work like this...

[EDIT]
The last issue I'm facing is when I try to hide every messages (cells) and go back to the bottom of the TableView so new messages are displayed I can't hide cells that are out of the viewport.

Here's the code :

```
- (void)disableScrollAndHideMessages {
    [self.chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
    self.chatTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.chatTableView.bounces = NO;

    // hide messages
    for (ChatMessageViewCell *messageViewCell in visibleCells) {
        [messageViewCell hide];
    }
}
```

I tried to hide every cells with a loop on `[self.chatTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:i];` but it's crashing because the cells out of the viewport aren't reachable.

I got the same problem when the keyboard is shown, if the messages disappear because of the timer (messages automatically disappear after X seconds) while it's shown, when I hide it, the messages out of the viewport are still visible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this very easily in a similar app...

First, use a `UITableView`. Tableviews are built to handle large numbers of items being displayed. The memory used is only enough to display everything on screen. With a scrollview you would have to load every chat into memory and put it on the screen. If there are thousands of messages thats a lot of memory and potentially a slow or crashing app.

Code it to work from top to bottom like a normal `UITableView` would work. Row 0 goes at the top with the contents of the latest chat message. Then row 1 and row 2 and so on...

Then do this...

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

This will rotate the tableview and all of its contents by 180 degrees so now the latest chat is at the bottom but all of the cells are upside down.

So, in the cell subclass do this in the init method...

```
self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

This will rotate the content of the cell through 180 degrees also. This puts the contents of the cell the right way up again.

So now, in 2 lines of code you have exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: This look like an awesome way of dealing with it !  
I've seen that I can disable the scroll in a TableView so I think it's going to do the job.  
I'll try to implement this ASAP so I can make it the accepted answer if it works :)

Comment: I forgot that I had some animations running when a message is added. The previous messages are moving up and the new one come from the left (starting out of screen). It looks complicated to do with a TableView no ? Plus the fact that each message can be different in length so I need to change the cell height accordingly. What do you think ?

Comment: @Comawoot what you are talking about is built in functionality with UITableView. If you are targeting iOS 8 and above then automatic cell height is built into Auto Layout. There is a function on UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: the option for animation of UITableViewRowAnimationLeft will animate the row in from the left.

Comment: @Comawoot if you're targeting less than iOS 8 then you still have the heightForRow method to make each row a different height.

Comment: @Comawoot even without the built in functions it would still be just as easy with a table view. Cells are just views so can be animated and so on just as any view can be animated.

Comment: you rock man! I'm going to try that tomorrow, I've been busy on another issue lately :)

Comment: Ok I finally had time to try your solution, and I must say that it's doing pretty much what I want, but there's still a problem when I disable the scroll and get back at the bottom of the TableView.
I updated my question to explain the issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Comawoot the bottom is actually the top of the table. If you want the cell to s scroll so it's at the bottom of the screen then use `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` as the top of the table view is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Comawoot what is `[messageViewCell hide];` and why are you trying to hide them? You shouldn't need to hide anything.

Comment: The messages are disappearing 6 seconds after appearance, it's the way this chat has been designed. So I'm already hiding cells after 6 seconds of appearance. When the user tap on the screen, I'm making every message visible and he's able to scroll through them, then when he tap again on the screen, they need to disappear and the scroll need to go back at the bottom (Top in our case as you pointed out in the previous comment). That's when I'm trying to scroll back and hide every messages that I'm running into this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @Comawoot ah, I see. You're not thinking in table views though :D Don't hide the messages. Remove them from the table view. `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:...];` You can create a timer from when the cell is displayed `- (void)tableView:willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:` and then remove that cell after the timer triggers. This will "hide" the cells and update the scroll size and everything for you.

Comment: @Comawoot you'll also need to update the number of rows method when you hide the rows. If you have 10 to start with and then hide 2 of them your number of rows method should now return 8. (You can do this by removing the data from the array you are using to populate the table when you remove the cell).

Comment: Man, you're the boss xD I don't know why I didn't thought about it from the beginning... I was blindly following my initial plan who wasn't involving tables :D

Comment: @Comawoot no worries. Happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you should increase the size of your scrollView's contentView by the height of the new message plus spacing, get the position of the last message in the scrollView's contentView and add the new message relative to that. You can do that like so:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width ,scrollView.contentSize.height + newMessageView.frame.size.height + spacing);
newMessageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, lastMessageView.frame.origin.y + spacing, newMessageView.frame.size.width, newMessageView.frame.size.height);
[scrollView addSubView:newMessageView];
```